# portuguese characters with webservice objective c

Tags: objective-c, web-services

i am calling a webservice and receiving data with portuguese characters

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request addValue:@"application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding0 error:nil];

even added the iso-8859-1 to the header but always receive a dictionary like this:

```
    {
    name = "Lu\U00eds Brito";  
    user = lbrito;
    userId = 16;
},
    {
    name = "Nelson Azevedo";
    user = nazevedo;
    userId = 17;
},
    {
    name = "M\U00f3nica Morais";
    user = mmorais;
    userId = 19;
},
```

tried to put in NSISOLatin1StringEncoding the options but doesnt do anything
anyone knows a solution, searched around didnt find much help, thks.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is defined to be always encoded in UTF-8 (it can use UTF-16 and UTF-32 as well, but not ISO 8859-1)

Comment: what can i do then, cant change the webservice

Comment: use NSJSONSerialization without any encoding options and you'll get perfectly useable NSStrings for your user's names.

Comment: NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:nil error:nil]; doesnt change anything :(

Comment: well, what do you expect? Maybe you should clarify your question.

Comment: M\U00f3nica Morais should be Mónica Morais and Lu\U00eds Brito should be Luís Brito

Comment: That is exactly what you get when you extract the values for the dictionary with `[dictionary objectForString:@"key"]`, i.e. NSJSONSerialization handles this for you. If you look at the raw JSON, you will always see these characters encoded as \u1234

Comment: Please post an example of the original HTTP response including its headers.

Comment: i am putting it in a sqlite database after receiving, maybe thats the problem